# How to perform sorting in mutable array with its dictionary key values in swift 3?

Tags: swift

This is my mutable array before sorting

```
(
    {
    name = "Cape";
    size = 592;
},
    {
    name = "Bayshore";
    size = 1012;
})
```

> I want to sort the array with its key 'name' as String and the 'size' as Int.

This is what I have tried so far

```
let descriptor: NSSortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true )
interestedArray.sortedArray(using: [descriptor])
```

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning the code.I have edited the question.Please help

Comment: What do you mean by "*sort the array with its key 'name' as String and the 'size' as Int.*"? What's your expected result? Also, you should almost certainly be using a Swift `Array` rather than `NSMutableArray`.

Answer (score 1):

`sortedArray` is designed to consider multiple sort descriptors:

```
let nameDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true )
let sizeDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "size", ascending: true )
let sortedArray = interestedArray.sortedArray(using: [nameDescriptor, sizeDescriptor])
```

If you want to sort the array in place use

```
interestedArray.sort(using: [nameDescriptor, sizeDescriptor])
```

Comment: Ok. But what if I want to sort by only one key?

Comment: Then use only one descriptor like in the question. But you asked *I want to sort ... 'name' **and**  'size'.*

Comment: Consider that `sortedArray` does not sort the array in place, it returns the sorted array.

Comment: I want them in different sorts.

Comment: I want to perform one sorting filter for 'name' and the other filter for 'size'.

Comment: Then use two sort methods with a specific sort descriptor for each sort operation.

Comment: It works for me using 'sort' instead of 'sortedArray'.

Comment: Thanks for the help @vadian
You saved me.